# how to work with divs in HTML5

Tags: html

I just started to work with HTML and I wanted to make a site which has got a colour on the upper side, an another colour on the lower side. I did some research, and I discovered that you got to work with divs. Can you make a nice div in HTML, or do you got to make a div in css (which does fit correct to my site)?

Comment: better start with a tutorial, people here are supporters, not teachers.

Comment: HTML is not a programming language

Comment: A div in HTML is neither nice or not. It just is. It's just a way to classify content. The styling and positioning of the div is handled by the css which targets it.

Answer (score 2):

Create your divs in your body with id's

```
<div id="upper"></div>
<div id="lower"></div>
```

and then using css you can change some attributes such as color and size, for example in either an external css file or inside of style tags you can do this.

```
#upper {
background-color: blue;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

#lower{

}
```

w3schools.com is a great resource for beginner web development, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Div is a html element. You can set its properties through css but a div doesn;t exsist in css. It is just a way to divide up section in html. Here is some basic information about divs.[Divs Info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp)